# An exponential - logarithmic equation / inequality

Tags: logarithms

$x$ , $a$  ∈  $ℝ$

$x$ > $0$  ,  $a \neq 1$

Is there any $x$ that makes the below equation have only one repeated root?
How about other states?
[ From root we mean root of x with a given a ]

For example a $x$ that makes the equation have two simple roots or maybe no roots?

Equation :

$$\log_ax = a ^ x$$

(It is good to note that the x can be generalized to any other function.)

Comment: Roots for $x$ given $a$ or for $a$ given $x$?

Comment: You can get 2 simple roots for example, given $a=1.2, x=1.258 \text{ and } x=14.767$ are roots. No x roots could be obtained for base $a=1.7$. There are many such values (of both types) but I don't know of a general expression for the roots. For the case of no roots, you can try the derivative and see when the local max. does not exist.

Comment: Great. I had been working on it a long time ago.I have reached some results.But I want to know that is this equation solved anywhere or not?The bigger problem is the proof of results...

Answer (score 0):

We need to assume $a>0$, otherwise the functions are not defined.

Let $f_a(x) = a^x$. Let's note that $\log_a x = f_a^{-1}(x)$. We have therefore equation
$$ f_a^{-1}(x) = f_a(x)$$
The graphs of functions $f_a$ and $f_a^{-1}$ are mirror reflections of each other in respect to the line $y=x$. By analyzing the graph of $f_a(x)$ we can identify several cases:

**Case 1:** $0<a<1$.

There is a single point $x_0\in(0,1)$ for which
$$ f_a^{-1}(x_0) = f_a(x_0) = x_0$$
$x_0$ can be found using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
\begin{align} a^x = x &\Rightarrow xa^{-x} = 1 \Rightarrow \\
&\Rightarrow - x  \ln a\cdot e^{-x\ln a } =  -\ln a \Rightarrow \\
&\Rightarrow -x \ln a = W(-\ln a) \end{align}
$$x_0 = \frac{1}{-\ln a}W_0(-\ln a) $$

However, it doesn't have to be the only solution of equation $f_a(x) = f_a^{-1}(x)$. Indeed, if we calculate
$$ f_a'(x_0) - (f_a^{-1})'(x_0) = \ln a\cdot a^{x_0} - \frac{1}{x_0\ln a} = x_0\ln a - \frac{1}{x_0\ln a} = \frac{1}{W_0(-\ln a)} - W_0(-\ln a)$$
we see it can be of any sign; and if it is negative (that is $W_0(-\ln a) > 1$, equivalently $a<e^{-e}$), then with the facts that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} (a^x - \log_a x) = -\infty$$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} (a^x - \log_a x) = a>0  $$
it means that there must be at least two additional roots, one in the interval $(0,x_0)$ and one in the interval $(x_0, 1)$.

To prove that for $0<a<e^{-e}$ there are exactly three solutions, and for $e^{-e}\le a<1$ there is exactly one solution, let us analyze the derivative of $a^x - \log_a x$:

\begin{align} & (a^x - \log_a x)' = 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow & \quad \ln a\cdot a^{x} - \frac{1}{x\ln a} \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow & \quad x\ln a\cdot e^{x \ln a} = \frac{1}{\ln a} \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow & \quad x  = \frac{1}{\ln a}W(\frac{1}{\ln a}) \end{align}

If $a> e^{-e}$ this equation doesn't have a solution, which leads to $(a^x - \log_a x)' > 0$ for all $x>0$ and $a^x - \log_a x$ is strictly increasing. That means it has only one root, and we have already found it, $x=x_0$.

The situation for border value $a= e^{-e}$ is similar. The derivative has only one root, which still means that $a^x - \log_a x$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$, and it has only one root $x=x_0 $.

If $a<e^{-e}$ the stuation is more complicated. Function $a^x - \log_a x$ is increasing on the interval $\big(0,\frac{1}{\ln a}W_0(\frac{1}{\ln a})\big)$, decreasing on $\big(\frac{1}{\ln a}W_0(\frac{1}{\ln a}),\frac{1}{\ln a}W_{-1}(\frac{1}{\ln a})\big)$ and again increasing on $\big(\frac{1}{\ln a}W_{-1}(\frac{1}{\ln a}),\infty\big) $. In each interval there can be at most one root, and we already know there are at least three roots for $a>e^{-e}$, so there are exactly 3 roots, one in each of these intervals. We know the exact location of only one, in the middle interval ($x=x_0$).

**Case 2:** $1<a<a_c$ where $a_c$ is the value of parameter $a$ for which the graph of function $a^x$ is tangent to the line $y=x$ (see Case 3).

In this case there are two points where $ f_a^{-1}(x) = f_a(x) = x$ given by
$$ x_1 = \frac{1}{-\ln a}W_0(-\ln a) $$ 
$$ x_2 = \frac{1}{-\ln a}W_{-1}(-\ln a) $$

**Case 3:** $a=a_c$.

In this case there will be only solution, at the point where the graph $a^x$ is tangent to $y=x$. We can find both the value of $x_0$ and the value of $a_c$ by the conditions
$$ \big(f_{a_c}(x_0) = x_0 \big) \land \big(f_{a_c}'(x_0) =1) $$
$$ \big({a_c}^{x_0} = x_0 \big) \land \big(\ln {a_c} \cdot {a_c}^{x_0} =1) $$
$$ \big(x_0 \ln {a_c} = 1\big) \land \big(\ln {a_c} \cdot e^{x_0 \ln {a_c}} =1)$$
$$ a_c = e^{1/e}, \qquad x_0 = e$$

**Case 4:** $a>a_c$.

In this case $f_a(x) > x$ and there are no solutions.

To sum up, there are
\begin{array}{lll} \text{3 roots} & \text{for }0<a<e^{-e} & \text{one of them is }x=\frac{1}{-\ln a}W_0(-\ln a) \\ 
\text{1 root} & \text{for }e^{-e}\le x < 1 & x=\frac{1}{-\ln a}W_0(-\ln a)  \\
\text{2 roots} & \text{for }1<a<e^{1/e} & x\in\{\frac{1}{-\ln a}W_0(-\ln a),\frac{1}{-\ln a}W_{-1}(-\ln a)\} \\
\text{1 root} & \text{for }x = e^{1/e} & x=e  \\
\text{no roots} & \text{for }x > e^{1/e} & 
\end{array}

Actually finding $a(x)$ rather than $x(a)$ is easier:
$$  e^{x\ln a} = \frac{\ln x}{\ln a }$$
$$  x\ln a \cdot e^{x\ln a} = x \ln x$$
$$ x\ln a = W(x\ln x)$$
$$ \ln a = \frac1x W(x\ln x)$$
which allows us to create a plot:

[image]

Comment: Exactly...I have found these results to.But I think case 1 should be divided into three cases just like the case that a>1 . In that case the borders are the inverse of $e^{1/e}$

Comment: You are right that there are more cases, but the critical value is $a = e^{-e}$. I'll work on my answer.

Comment: Ok, improved my answer, identifying two subcases for $a<1$ and creating a plot of $x(a)$.

Comment: Great.Our reaults are same.Do you think that this equation is useful somewhere in science?It can be generalized to any other function and we can have equation and inequalitis for all two of these tree functions: $u$ , $\log_au$ , $a ^ u$

Comment: I've never seen this particular equation used in science, though Lambert W function has some applications. I also believe that the structure of the solutions of equation $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ may depend a lot on what the function $f$ is, so the results can't be easily generalized. (Example: for $f(x) =\frac{a}{x}$ the solution is $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, for any $a$.)